# Order by in a self-referencing table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Let's say I have the following table with data:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
| id | name      | parent_id | prev_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
| 1  | Section 1 | NULL      | NULL    |
| 2  | Item 1.1  | 1         | NULL    |
| 3  | Item 1.2  | 1         | 2       |
| 4  | Item 1.3  | 1         | 3       |
| 5  | Section 2 | NULL      | 1       |
| 6  | Item 2.1  | 5         | NULL    |
| 7  | Item 2.2  | 5         | 6       |
| 8  | Item 2.3  | 5         | 7       |
| 9  | Item 1.4  | 1         | 4       |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

Here's how it works:

- `parent_id` and `prev_id` are both foreign keys to `id`
- `parent_id` is used to differentiate between a section and sub-section (item)
- i.e. if `parent_id` is NULL, then it is a section; otherwise it is an item
- `prev_id` is used to indicate the last section or last item in the section
- i.e. if the row is a section, then `prev_id` will point to the row of the previous section; if the row is an item, then `prev_id` will point to the row of the last  item in the section
- if `prev_id` is NULL, then it is the first section or first item in the section
- if `parent_id` and `prev_id` are both NULL, then it is the first section

**So, is there a way to order it using SQL so that it looks like this:**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
| id | name      | parent_id | prev_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
| 1  | Section 1 | NULL      | NULL    |
| 2  | Item 1.1  | 1         | NULL    |
| 3  | Item 1.2  | 1         | 2       |
| 4  | Item 1.3  | 1         | 3       |
| 9  | Item 1.4  | 1         | 4       | <---
| 5  | Section 2 | NULL      | 1       |
| 6  | Item 2.1  | 5         | NULL    |
| 7  | Item 2.2  | 5         | 6       |
| 8  | Item 2.3  | 5         | 7       |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

I would like so that

- The first section, followed by its items, appears at the top
- For each subsequent section, show the section followed by the items of that section

**Edit:** Here's a query that I came up with:

```
SELECT id, name, parent_id, prev_id FROM
((
    SELECT id, name, parent_id, prev_id, id AS some_id
    FROM learning_paths
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT id, name, parent_id, prev_id, parent_id AS some_id
    FROM learning_paths
    WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
)) t
ORDER BY t.some_id, prev_id
```

Comment: what is the query you have come up with so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version works:

```
order by coalesce(parentid, id),
         (parentid is null) desc,
         coalesce(previd, parentid, id),
         previd,
         id
```

There might be simpler versions around.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8103) is a SQL Fiddle (admittedly in Postgres, but that shouldn't make a difference for this problem).

Comment: Unfortunately, neither statements create the desired result.

Comment: @Mikey . . . It is fixed and tested.  I think I tried to take a short-cut the first time.